# My element foreignObject is not shown

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to add an foreignObject inside of SVG, but it is not shown. It is added inside the SVG. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

```
 body = d3.select('body')
 svg = body.append('svg').attr('height', 600).attr('width', 600)     

 var div= svg.append('foreignObject')
 .attr("width",50)
 .attr('height',50)
 .append("div")
 .attr("class", "tooltip")
 .style("opacity", 1);
  div.append('img')
 .attr("id", "img_tweet").attr("src", "")
 .attr("class", "imagen_tweet");
 div.append('div').attr("id", "texto_tweet");

document.getElementById('img_tweet').src="https://www.amrita.edu/sites/default/files/news-images/new/news-events/images/l-nov/grass.jpg";
document.getElementById('texto_tweet').innerHTML='message'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tzp3oe5a/

Comment: where are your html elements at jsfiddle? I see only a js there

Comment: @vaso123 I am using d3.js, this create element dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prefix the outer html with `xhtml` like this `.append("xhtml:div")`
You can read more about the explanation here [using foreignObject to add SVG dynamically using D3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035835/using-foreignobject-to-add-svg-dynamically-using-d3js)

```js
     body = d3.select('body')
     svg = body.append('svg').attr('height', 600).attr('width', 600)     
     
     var div= svg.append('foreignObject')
      .attr("width", 50)
     .attr("height", 50)
     .append("xhtml:div")
     .attr("class", "tooltip")
     .style("opacity", 1);
      div.append('img')
     .attr("id", "img_tweet").attr("src", "https://www.amrita.edu/sites/default/files/news-images/new/news-events/images/l-nov/grass.jpg")
     .attr("class", "imagen_tweet");
     div.append('div').attr("id", "texto_tweet");
     
    //document.getElementById('img_tweet').src="https://www.amrita.edu/sites/default/files/news-images/new/news-events/images/l-nov/grass.jpg";
    document.getElementById('texto_tweet').innerHTML='message'
```

```css
      div.tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        top:14px;
        left: 62px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100px;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 2px;
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 8px;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 999999;
      }

      .imagen_tweet{
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.js"></script>
```

Working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/tzp3oe5a/2/

Comment: Sorry about that, aren't you trying to display a div with image and text inside SVG? That seems to be working on my example.

Comment: yeah... but, can you help me with this? https://plnkr.co/edit/EAKmhEp2rj2x9nfFh3OU?p=preview

Comment: a foreignObject will be the tooltip, but it is not shown.

Comment: When I click on the circle, it should be positioned next to the circle. But it is as if it were hidden. Help me with this question, and I give you the best answer please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760582/position-tooltip-in-d3-js I initially did it with a div, but it is better with a foreignObjetc to save the position in the SVG.

Comment: I just need to display the foreignObject as a tooltip, next to the circle

Comment: Have you checked this http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/10699411, this example seems be using tooltip

Comment: I had already seen it, but in my case, if I zoom it is misaligned. I do not know why it does not work for me

Comment: look, can you help me with this please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764596/show-tooltip-by-clicking-on-a-circle

Comment: I have little experience with d3.js, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152295/discussion-between-yavg-and-azs06).